# How can I parse a simple Json response (multiple strings) in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

Ok, so I know how to parse more complex Json arrays but I cannot parse this one.

```
      ["1469972335822.png","1376959827781.png","1410482365226.jpg","azV5j2q_700b.jpg","1469773415064.jpg"]
```

I'm trying to parse each filename into an array of Strings, so it will look like

```
array[0] = "1469972335822.png"
array[1] = "1376959827781.png"
```

And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i=0 ; i<array.length() ; i++){
    Log.d(TAG, array.get(i).toString());
}
```